# Tkinter menubar class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make my code more efficient by have a class for creating a menu bar and its contents. No errors are being reported, but it won't make the bar. (I did have it working without a class, but can't seem to get it working again!)

```
from Tkinter import *

class MenuBar: #'player' is the name of the Tk window
    def __init__(self, menuname, Label, Drop_Label, Command, Separator = False):
        self.menubar = Menu(player)
        self.menuname = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = 0)
        self.menuname.add_command(label = Label, command = Command)

        if Separator == True:
            self.menuname.add_separator()

        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = Drop_Label, menu = menuname)

        self.Create()

    def Create(self):
        player.config(menu = self.menubar)

#example menu item
def addMenuBar():
    exitMenu = MenuBar("filemenu", "Exit", "File", onExit, True)
    #More menu items here, function to keep it tidier.

def onExit():
    #Code here

player = Tk()

addMenuBar()

player.mainloop()
```

This does draw the Tk window, but no menu bar options, where am I going wrong?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__` function just create a menu bar.
Create a function that adds menus and accept commands as a list of tuples:

```
from Tkinter import *

class MenuBar: #'player' is the name of the Tk window
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.menubar = Menu(parent)
        self.Create()

    def Create(self):
        player.config(menu = self.menubar)

    def add_menu(self, menuname, commands):
        menu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = 0)

        for command in commands:
            menu.add_command(label = command[0], command = command[1])
            if command[2]:
                menu.add_separator()

        self.menubar.add_cascade(label=menuname, menu=menu)

def onExit():
    import sys
    sys.exit()

def onOpen():
    print 'Open'

player = Tk()

menubar = MenuBar(player)

fileMenu = menubar.add_menu("File", commands = [("Open", onOpen, True), ("Exit", onExit, False)])

player.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't come up with any menu items using 2.7.11 on Mac. I do have code for the onExit function, just didn't include it on here.